# Dockerfile works fine locally but not in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I have a Dockerfile which starts with

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
```

Locally, this works perfectly. So I write my .gitlab-ci.yml file as follows:

```
docker-image:
  stage: containerise_requirements
  image: docker:19.03.1
  tag:
    - my-runner
  services:
    - docker:19.03.1-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  script:
    - docker pull $IMAGENAME:latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from $IMAGENAME:latest --tag $IMAGENAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $IMAGENAME:latest .
    - docker push $IMAGENAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push $IMAGENAME:latest
```

but now, I get the error

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.031MB

Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.7-slim
 ---> b5a7c089ece3
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
 ---> Running in 0d90afc1839b
Removing intermediate container 0d90afc1839b
 ---> b8c22c4288c7
Step 3/7 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
 ---> Running in 1052a5ffb708
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [39.1 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [98.2 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7899 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [5792 B]
Fetched 8212 kB in 2s (4828 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk
```

This surprises me - if the Dockerfile builds locally, why wouldn't it build during CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python:3.7-slim is now based on Debian 10. There is no such package openjdk-8-jdk. So either install openjdk-11-jdk or add sid Repo sources. Most probably, your local Python Image is older and therefore based on an older Debian (e.g. Stretch).

Comment: But why would it work when I locally run ```docker build -t my-tag .```?

Comment: Thanks - can confirm that changing to `python:3.7-stretch` allowed everything to go back to working as before. Perhaps this is a lesson in using hashes rather than labels?

Comment: Glad it worked out :) When working with 3rd-party Images you have to read the documentation conscientiously (and hope that it is good and correct). The Python Image doc on Docker Hub states the fact you experienced. But don't you worry, such things happen all the time with docker; and as you said... Experience :)